# response tap gesture of two pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two pages: PageA and PageB. PageB is a transparent page.

Tap PageA will print `tab PageA`, tap PageB will print `tab PageB`.

There is a button in PageA which on tap will jump to PageB.

Now in PageB, will print `tab PageB` when I tap PageB.

But I want print `tab PageB` **and** `tab PageA` when I tap PageB.

**I want capture tap gesture in both PageA and PageB.**

Anyway can do this in flutter?

Here is test code:

```dart
class _PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PageA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('tab PageA');
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PageA')),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Push PageB'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                PageRouteBuilder(
                  opaque: false,
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
                    return _PageB();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class _PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  const _PageB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_PageB> createState() => _PageBState();
}

class _PageBState extends State<_PageB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('tab PageB');
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'This is a transparency page',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i didnt get it. what do you want to do??
do you want to get stacked route or you want to pass a function to next page?

Comment: @pmatatias I want capture tap gesture in both PageA and PageB.

Answer (score 0):

In page A do this:

```
_onButtonAClick(){
 print('tab PageA');
}
```

and use it like this:

```
onTap: _onButtonAClick,
```

and in your page B set this in your constructor:

```
class _PageB extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onPageAButtonClick;
  const _PageB({Key? key, required this.onPageAButtonClick}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_PageB> createState() => _PageBState();
}
```

and in your page A when navigate to B do this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                PageRouteBuilder(
                  opaque: false,
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
                    return _PageB(onPageAButtonClick:_onButtonAClick);
                  },
                ),
              );
```

and then in your page B button call this:

```
onTap: () {
        widget.onPageAButtonClick();
        print('tab PageB');
      },
```

Comment: Thanks but I want capture tap gesture in both PageA and PageB.

Comment: Maybe it's impossible in flutter?

Comment: with this way you can capture it programmatically, both button in Page A and B Call same function.